# remove null character from string

Tags: string, go, replace, removing-whitespace

I want to check if string is empty and parse the string in time.

Please find the below code

```
valueStr = strings.Replace(string(valueStr), " ", "", -1)
valueStr = strings.Replace(string(valueStr), "\t", "", -1)
valueStr = strings.Replace(string(valueStr), "\n", "", -1)
valueStr = strings.Replace(string(valueStr), "\r", "", -1)
var re = regexp.MustCompile(`\s`)
valueStr = re.ReplaceAllString(valueStr, "")

if valueStr != "" {
    fmt.Printf("-------- valueStr %c: \n", valueStr)         // o/p =>  -------- valueStr %!c(string= ):
    fmt.Printf("-------- valueStr %#v: \n", valueStr)        // o/p => -------- valueStr "\x00":
    fmt.Printf("-------- valueStr %x: \n", valueStr)         // o/p =>  -------- valueStr 00:
    fmt.Println("-------- valueStr length: ", len(valueStr)) // o/p => -------- valueStr length:  1

    // considering valueStr is not empty, parse string to time

    time, err := time.Parse(TIME_FORMAT, strings.TrimSpace(valueStr))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("-------- Error converting time: ", err) // o/p => -------- Error converting time:  parsing time " " as "15:04:05": cannot parse " " as "15"
        return
    }
} else {
    // another code
}
```

How to remove this empty character from string? Or check if string contains this empty character?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can remove `\x00` runes from a string the same way you can remove any other runes:

```
valueStr = strings.Replace(valueStr, "\x00", "", -1)
```

Example:

```
s := "a\x00b"
fmt.Printf("%q\n", s)
s = strings.Replace(s, "\x00", "", -1)
fmt.Printf("%q\n", s)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/bBF5dWyQXKw)):

```
"a\x00b"
"ab"
```

### Using `strings.Replacer`

Also note that you can substitute the multiple replaces with a single operation by using  [`strings.Replacer`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Replacer), and it will also be more efficient as it only iterates over the input once (and there will be only one `string` allocated for the result, no matter how many substrings you want to replace).

For example:

```
s := " \t\n\rabc\x00"
fmt.Printf("%q\n", s)

r := strings.NewReplacer(" ", "", "\t", "", "\n", "", "\r", "", "\x00", "")
s = r.Replace(s)
fmt.Printf("%q\n", s)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/iX8X6Rf4qfN)):

```
" \t\n\rabc\x00"
"abc"
```

Also note that it's enough to create a `string.Replacer` once, and you can store it in a (global) variable and reuse it, it is even safe to use it concurrently from multiple goroutines.

### Using `strings.Map()`

Also note that if you only want to replace (remove) single `rune`s and not multi-rune (or multi-byte) substrings, you can also use [`strings.Map()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Map) which might be even more efficient than `strings.Replacer`.

First define a function that tells which `rune`s to replace (or remove if you return a negative value):

```
func remove(r rune) rune {
    switch r {
    case ' ', '\t', '\n', '\r', 0:
        return -1
    }
    return r
}
```

And then using it:

```
s := " \t\n\rabc\x00"
fmt.Printf("%q\n", s)

s = strings.Map(remove, s)
fmt.Printf("%q\n", s)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/_BCdcnaszLR)):

```
" \t\n\rabc\x00"
"abc"
```

### Benchmarks

We might think `strings.Map()` will be superior as it only have to deal with `rune`s which are just `int32` numbers, while `strings.Replacer` have to deal with `string` values which are headers (length+data pointer) plus a series of bytes.

But we should know that `string` values are stored as UTF-8 byte sequences in memory, which means `strings.Map()` have to decode the `rune`s from the UTF-8 byte sequence (and encode the runes back to UTF-8 in the end), while `strings.Replacer` does not: it may simply look for byte sequence matches without decoding the `rune`s. And `strings.Replacer` is highly optimized to take advantage of such "tricks".

So let's create a benchmark to compare them:

We'll use these for the benchmarks:

```
var r = strings.NewReplacer(" ", "", "\t", "", "\n", "", "\r", "", "\x00", "")

func remove(r rune) rune {
    switch r {
    case ' ', '\t', '\n', '\r', 0:
        return -1
    }
    return r
}
```

And we run benchmarks on different input strings:

```
func BenchmarkReplaces(b *testing.B) {
    cases := []struct {
        title string
        input string
    }{
        {
            title: "None",
            input: "abc",
        },
        {
            title: "Normal",
            input: " \t\n\rabc\x00",
        },
        {
            title: "Long",
            input: "adsfWR \t\rab\nc\x00 \t\n\rabc\x00asdfWER\n\r",
        },
    }

    for _, c := range cases {
        b.Run("Replacer-"+c.title, func(b *testing.B) {
            for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
                r.Replace(c.input)
            }
        })
        b.Run("Map-"+c.title, func(b *testing.B) {
            for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
                strings.Map(remove, c.input)
            }
        })
    }

}
```

And now let's see the benchmark results:

```
BenchmarkReplaces/Replacer-None-4    100000000   12.3 ns/op    0 B/op  0 allocs/op
BenchmarkReplaces/Map-None-4         100000000   16.1 ns/op    0 B/op  0 allocs/op
BenchmarkReplaces/Replacer-Normal-4  20000000    92.7 ns/op    6 B/op  2 allocs/op
BenchmarkReplaces/Map-Normal-4       20000000    92.4 ns/op   16 B/op  2 allocs/op
BenchmarkReplaces/Replacer-Long-4     5000000   234 ns/op     64 B/op  2 allocs/op
BenchmarkReplaces/Map-Long-4          5000000   235 ns/op     80 B/op  2 allocs/op
```

Despite expectations, `string.Replacer` performs pretty good, just as good as `strings.Map()` due to it not having to decode and encode runes.

Comment: @Bhavana Added another solution using `strings.Map()`, see edited answer.

Comment: Why is strings.Map() more efficient than strings.Replacer? Is it, because it looks only at specific runes instead of whole substrings?

Comment: @JonasTepe Yes, checking single `rune`s (which are just `int32` numbers) is always more efficient than checking `string`s, which is a header (length+data pointer) plus a series of bytes.

Comment: @icza Makes sense. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @JonasTepe I added another section comparing performances, `strings.Replacer` is highly optimized and performs just as good as `strings.Map()` (due to it not having to decode and encode runes from the UTF-8 byte sequences).

Comment: Seems like, both allocate, if there are matches to be replaced. For the new string to be returned.

Comment: @JonasTepe Yes, they have to. The only case when they could avoid allocation is if the result would be a substring of the input, in which case the input could be sliced and returned. But this check is not built into them (and it's not worth the complexity).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is your situation, but in my case, I was receiving `uint16` slices from Windows Syscalls. In that case, the data is also terminated by null element. To deal with that, you can use the `windows` package:

```
package main

import (
   "fmt"
   "golang.org/x/sys/windows"
)

func main() {
   a := []uint16{77, 97, 114, 99, 104, 0}
   s := windows.UTF16ToString(a)
   fmt.Printf("%q\n", s) // "March"
}
```

https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/sys/windows#UTF16ToString

Answer (score 0):

In current Python (as of november 2021) and under Windows 10, this piece of code worked for me:

```
s = str.replace(s, "\x00", "", -1)
```

Comment: don't comments on answer section.

Comment: This is a question about Go :)